# How do you access a variable stored in a function?

Tags: python

```
def func():
    number = 1
def func2():
    print number
```

Why would this code not print "1"?(Besides the fact that I didn't call the functions?)

Comment: have a look for global variables and scopes, or make use of return

Comment: Jo have to define a class variable for this.

Comment: Why don't you return the number and call the function in the second?

Comment: Think about the nightmare you would be in if the code *would* print "1".  If that were the case and you had 100 functions in a file, you would have to make sure that the variables in each function were different so they didn't overwrite each other.  It would be logistical hell.

Comment: @SethMMorton yeah, you mentioning that just makes me stressed out a little...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you're TRYING to do. My magic crystal ball is rusty.

```
def func1():
    user_input = raw_input("prompt")
    return user_input
def func2(the_input):
    print the_input

that_same_input = func1()
func2(that_same_input)
```

If you're on Python3, substitute `input("prompt")` for `raw_input("prompt")` and `print(the_input)` for `print the_input`

Functions do one of two things. They either make a calculation and return an output, or they mutate some structure into something you want. If they do anything OTHER than this you should (usually) refactor. Right now you're trying to make your `func1` set a global variable, then call it from somewhere else. Well, kind of.

What you're REALLY trying to do is to make a set of calculations with `func1`. You want it to get some user input, then report back what that user input IS. In your original example you tried to save it to a variable, but since variables inside functions don't have global scope that's not working for you. Let's return the value instead and save it to a variable OUTSIDE the function.

Once we've done that, we can make another function accept that as a PARAMETER, and pass it the variable to work with! See? Mutate, or calculate and return. Those are your options.

Answer (score 2):

you return it

```
def func(n):
    number = n+1
    return number

something = func(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define `number` in `func`, it's not a global name; it's local to `func`. When you call `func2`, the `number` that you defined in `func` doesn't exist.  You can create a new one, but it doesn't have anything to do with the `number` from another function.  In fact, this code will throw NameError because there is no variable named `number` in `func2`.

Comment: but what if I'm getting user input?

Comment: Why would that affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, you can use `global` keyword, here is a short example:

```
def func():
    global number
    number = 1
def func2():
    print number
```

Now if `func2` is called after `func` call, it will print 1 just as you would expect.

However, global variables are **not** exactly the best practice, you should probably avouid using them unless you absolutely have to, in which case the code above should help.

You can also check out python docs section on the subject: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value , might be helpful.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work, is it because I'm getting user input?

Comment: Egh, please don't let him use `global`! :)

Comment: @user3566607 SethMMorton commented on your answer with a great reason why :). It boils down to polluting your namespace unnecessarily.

Comment: @user3566607 How exactly didn't it work? I mean, what was wrong? And what do you mean by "getting user input"? If `func` was called and its execution finished, there *will* be a global variable named `number` with value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to define "number = 1"? just do

```
    number = 1
    def func2():
        print number
```